# Acegi Upgrade - BadCredentialsException

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am upgrading a legacy Grails application and also upgrade the acegi plugin from 0.4 to 0.5.2. When I try to log into the application, I am getting a BadCredentialsException: with "User does not exist".

The user definitely exists in the database and the credentials are definitely correct. I don't know much about the acegi plugin but have been reading up and from what I understand there should not have been any upgrade issues. I am also upgrading Grails from 1.0.3 to 1.3.7 at the same time, so that could be related to. Any other ideas?

Thanks.

```
org.springframework.security.event.authentication.AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent[source=org.springframework.security.providers.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@9a501e93: Principal: bwalsh@pps.com; Password: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: false; Details: org.springframework.security.ui.WebAuthenticationDetails@380f4: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 915D5CDB8F5A0AE07EC13F435FA66690; Not granted any authorities]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BadCredentialsException means the password check failed. Looks like a misconfiguration of the password hashing algorithm - is the `algorithm` attribute set correctly?

The default is

```
algorithm = 'SHA'
```

but it should be overridden in your `SecurityConfig.groovy` if you use a different approach.

btw - you should be upgrading to http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core :)